# better way of representing the above condition in loop

Tags: java, loops

I have the below scenario in which the problem statement was given to me is that
A wife calls her programmer husband and tells him while you are out, buy some milk and the husband never returns home , now i have to add this in loop so what i have tried is

```
while (you are out)
{Buy some milk;
}
Finally {
Return home;
}
```

now my question is that I have to express the above condition in loop , so i have evaluated as shown above , please advise can this above condition can be expresses i more precise manner in loop  or it can be better expressed in java 8 more precisely

please advise how this can be better represented in java loops or can we exoress in java new for loops

Comment: @sanketMakani , Please read the problem statement first , please advise can this be better expressed in some other loop

Answer (score 1):

What the wife actually meant is

```
if (youAreOut()) {
    buyMilk();
}
```

Since it does not make sense to buy milk repeatedly.

However the programmer husband took her words literally and did

```
while (youAreOut()) {
    buyMilk();
}
```

and thus never returned because he now spends his life buying milk.

Comment: how will you make sure that he will never return home